# Master page from external library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to put my master pages in a central library so I can use them in several projects without having the maintanance nightmare.
Everything is refactored in a generic and central way, they are all in a "shared" namespace.
But if put them in a seperate project, I can't reference them

Comment: What is the feasibility of, say, using a StringBuilder to build html within the external code, and build master page html that way? I want to "externalize" an admin view so it can just be part of a library that is dropped in to a project with no further action required on the dev's part. But how?

Comment: Maybe a stringbuilder is possible, but that would be a nightmare to maintain, no?

Comment: For anybody bumping in to this post (like I did several years after): Phil Haack's answer is in the answers under my account.

Comment: it's at the bottom of this post. It's mainly a negative. Sorry if I got your hopes up. http://stackoverflow.com/a/261269/11333

Comment: It's all good. Knowledge is power, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can put that actual .master pages in an external library. You can place your own customer MasterPage-derived class in the library, and have your client apps derive from that, but I don't think that's what your intent is, since you're tagged with asp.net-mvc (implying very narrow views without much logic, and probably no code-behinds).

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to reference a master (nor, for that matter, an ASPX or ASCX) from an external library. Wish I had better news for you. (And I actually hope I'm wrong; I hope someone else here has figured out a technique for this, as I'd like to use that kind of thing myself on occasion.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference's sake, I'll put Phil's mail here too:

> Sorry for the late response. You could try using a VirtualPathProvider, but this would require full trust. Other than that, I don't know of any way to do this.
>
> Phil

so there you go.